# Locked entities in postgres after retrieval

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

We have a table in postgres that we use for our system configurations, from which i want to delete configurations with certain ids. The problem is that just before the deletion, we have some code that fetches some of the configuration entries and on the next step (the deletion one) i can't delete them because the rows are locked. I've checked the pg_locks table and each configuration retrieval's transaction stays in postgres for around a minute. And it stays in status "idle in transaction", while the deletion step is waiting on it.

This is how we retrieve the configuration entities

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("some query");
...
list = query.getResultList();
```

There's no transaction involved, we don't really add any transactional jta, ejb annotations, i guess it's added automatically and after this query is where it gets locked.

And this is how we try to delete the rows

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(namedQuery);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Thats it. Nothing special, yet since some rows are locked, the query fails on waiting for the transaction to finish. Any ideas ?

I've tried seemingly everything. Setting hibernate's autocommit mode to true, setting the locktype when executing the queries to pessimistic read/writes, sending over query hints with the queries with max transaction times, executing the queries in separate JTA transactions, executing them in the same transaction, nothing seems to work, the delete query always 'hangs'

Comment: I've experienced something similar in the past, Did you check "pg_locks" before running the select query? There might be other other process that are locking the table, Can you kill all process which deal with DB if you are in DEV env? How big is the configuration table ? If you run the query directly in whatever tool you use to deal with the DB, Does it take that long to retrieve the data ?

Comment: Nothing locks it before the select query. It's just the select query that locks the delete query. The config table is not that big, the select only selects a few rows of it and takes little to no time to retrieve them. Then the code goes on to the delete statement and gets stuck there because of the selects (Checked that in pg_locks).

Comment: When you run the select query in the PostgreSQL console, Does it retrieve the results as quick as you expected ?

Comment: Yes, anyways i found the problem. The select query wasn't blocking anything, There was another delete query before the select that was locking the transaction but since the locks table in postgres only shows the last executed query in the transaction, it was showing the select one.